# Decrypting file in openssl 1.1.1c from encryption in openssl 1.0.2k

Tags: linux, encryption, openssl, decryption

We have to find a way to decrypt files produced in an older server using openssl version 1.0.2k in a upgraded server using openssl version 1.1.1c. We have several operational servers still using version 1.0.2k so we can't just upgrade everyone to the new version. All this came about during a required update of our software on newer servers to centos 8 from the older centos 7. Centos 8 uses 1.1.1c and centos 7 uses 1.0.2k.

In version 1.0.2k the command used to encrypt is:

```
tar -cz files.tar.gz | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e > secured.tar.gz.enc
```

In version 1.1.1c to decrypt the file I have tried:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -pbkdf2 -iter 1000000 -in secured.tar.gz.enc > test.tar.gz
```

I get the error:

```
bad decrypt
<numbers....>:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad 
decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:603:
```

From the information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43847627/1491879) it states that the error can be due to version 1.0.2k using md5 by default and version 1.1.1c using sha256. Thus using `-md md5`.

If I don't use `-pbkdf2 -iter 1000000` I get the error:

```
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
```

I have double checked the password and it is correct. Not sure what else could be the problem.

Comment: The warning about the depreciated key derivation, shouldn't be blocking the decryption process, are you able to decrypt the file on the original server?  I assume there is no way to update the older copy of OpenSSL?  Instead of replying with a comment, you should edit your question, to include the vital information necessary to answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound. Should I then remove the `-pbkdf2 -iter 1000000` section? I have updated the question with the reason why we can't just update all servers to the newer version.

Comment: So clearly `-pbkdf2 -iter 1000000` performs 1,000,000 iterations of the pbkdf2 to decrypt the file.  If the encryption process had not also performed the same number of iterations of pbkdf2 on the file then the end result of the blob of data wouldn't be correct.  It still would be extremely helpful to know, if you can run the command you suspect is correct, on the original (source) server?

Comment: The warning about deprecated key derivation is just a warning. The decryption should still continue. You can't use the `-pbkdf2` and `-iter` options unless they have also been used in the equivalent encryption command - unfortunately OpenSSL 1.0.2k does not support them.

Comment: thanks @Ramhound. I found using the command without the `-pbkdf2 -iter 1000000` parameters works on the older server. This works: `openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -in secured.tar.gz.enc > test.tar.gz`. I tried it on the new server without the argument and although it comes up with the warning it worked. Do you want to post the solution or should I?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the solution was to remove the `-pbkdf2 -iter 1000000` option. This just causes a warning message:

```
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
```

but is not required in the end. It is only required if the encryption also included this option. So the final solution is:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -in secured.tar.gz.enc > test.tar.gz
```

Thanks to @Ramhound for you help.